# when i update ReactNative to 0.43.2, pod install have trouble

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

when i update react-native to 0.43.2,
and pod install command on ios directory,
have trouble with this command

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Yoga (= 0.43.2.React)` required by `React/Core (0.43.2)`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Yoga (= 0.43.2.React)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

and my Podfile write like this

target 'my_app_title' do

```
pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
]

pod 'OneSignal'
pod 'ReactNativeFabric', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fabric'
```

end

anybody know about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your podfile

```
pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
```